# Multiple data Cake Paginator Query Result

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.4, paginator

I got the following result after using Paginate in Cake:

```
  array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'DestinationPhoto' => array(
                'id' => '1',
                'name' => 'picture.jpg',
                'destination_id' => '2'
            ),
            'Destinations' => array(
                'id' => '2',
                'country_id' => '2'
            ),
            'DestinationIdiom' => array(
                'id' => '3',
                'name' => 'TestName-1',
                'description' => 'TestDescription',
                'idiom' => 'English',
                'destination_id' => '2'
            )
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'DestinationPhoto' => array(
                'id' => '1',
                'name' => 'picture.jpg',
                'destination_id' => '2'
            ),
            'Destinations' => array(
                'id' => '2',
                'country_id' => '2'
            ),
            'DestinationIdiom' => array(
                'id' => '4',
                'name' => 'TestName-2',
                'description' => 'TestDescription-2',
                'idiom' => 'Spanish',
                'destination_id' => '2'
            )
        )
)
```

As it seems i got multiple instances of "DestinationPhoto", "Destinations" caused by differents "DestinationIdiom" in the same result, it's possible to join both "DestinationIdiom" to be displayed as the same result of the paginator? like

```
 array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'DestinationPhoto' => array(
                'id' => '1',
                'name' => 'huehuehuehuh.jpg',
                'destination_id' => '2'
            ),
            'Destinations' => array(
                'id' => '2',
                'country_id' => '2'
            ),
            'DestinationIdiom' => array(
                (int) 0 => array( 
                                    'id' => '3',
                        'name' => 'TestName-1',
                        'description' => 'TestDescription',
                        'idiom' => 'English',
                        'destination_id' => '2'
                                    )
                (int) 1 => array( 
                                    'id' => '3',
                        'name' => 'TestName-2',
                        'description' => 'TestDescription',
                        'idiom' => 'Spanish',
                        'destination_id' => '2'
                                    )
            )
        )
```

)

In the DestinationPhoto Controller i have the following:

```
        $this->paginate = array(
        'fields'=>array('DestinationPhoto.*','Destinations.*','DestinationIdiom.*'),
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'table' => 'destinations',
                'alias'=>'Destinations',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => '`DestinationPhoto`.`destination_id` = `Destinations`.`id`'
            ),
            array(
                'table' => 'destination_idioms',
                'alias'=>'DestinationIdiom',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => '`DestinationIdiom`.`destination_id` = `Destinations`.`id`'
            )
        ),
        'limit' => 20
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Model naming convention. Make it `Destination` instead of `Destinations`.

Bind the model association at run time like given below:

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'destinations',
            'alias'=>'Destination',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => '`DestinationPhoto`.`destination_id` = `Destinations`.`id`'
        )),
    'limit' => 20,
    'recursive' => '2'
    );

    $this->DestinationPhoto->Destination->bindModel(array('hasMany' => array('DestinationIdiom' => array('className' => 'DestinationIdiom',
                                                                                                         'foreignKey' => 'destination_id'))), false);
    $result = $this->paginate('Destination');
    pr($result);
    die;
```